# The maximum values at given positions across multiple lists of equal length

Tags: list-manipulation

What syntax will allow me to find the maximum values, at a given position, across multiple lists of equal length?

For example, suppose we have three lists `l1`, `l2`, and `l3`:

```
l1 = {1, 2, 1, 1, 5}

l2 = {2, 1, 1, 4, 5}

l3 = {3, 1, 2, 1, 4}
```

What syntax can be derived to obtain `lmax`:

```
lmax = {3, 2, 2, 4, 5}
```

Comment: I made a mistake in column 2. That might have been confusing. I edited lmax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html):

```
MapThread[Max, {l1, l2, l3}]
```

Or [`Map (/@)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) after [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html):

```
Max /@ ({l1, l2, l3}\[Transpose])
```